# How can invalid websocket requests be gracefully handled in Play 2.6?

Tags: scala, playframework

We have a play 2.6 app which uses websockets.  This is working great, but in our error logs we occasionally see the following:

```
[ERROR] [08/25/2017 16:00:44.770] [play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-35] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(play-dev-mode)] Internal server error, sending 500 response
java.lang.RuntimeException: WebSocket returned for non WebSocket request
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.executeHandler(AkkaHttpServer.scala:271)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:201)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$3(AkkaHttpServer.scala:107)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$23.onPush(Ops.scala:1172)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:499)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:462)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:368)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:571)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:457)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:546)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:725)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:740)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:513)
    at akka.actor.Actcorrectlyor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:511)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:650)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:527)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:496)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

After a little sleuthing it seems this occurs when an HTTP request without the correct `Connection` and/or `Upgrade` headers is made.  The play source is [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/7945944fd032261c7d8fbf11a3c8aba1935b3dd3/framework/src/play-akka-http-server/src/main/scala/play/core/server/AkkaHttpServer.scala).

We would like to log more detailed information to determine why this is happening (we suspect header-stripping firewalls), but unfortunately our websocket handler is never invoked (nothing is printed to console) when the error occurs:

```
def ws = WebSocketcorrectly.acceptOrResult[String, String] { implicit request =>
    println("Hello world") // Only printed for requests with valid headers
    ...
}
```

How can we insert some logging statements with access to the request headers and IP?

Comment: I can confirm that this error occurs when the proxy/firewall does not support websockets or are disabled (I've done tests disabling websockets in our WAF and getting this error)

Comment: Thanks, good to know!  I've got some higher priority stuff over the next couple of days but will return to this.  Next thing to try is using a filter, and if not then investigate writing a play plugin and will share anything I find out here.  I'd be grateful if you let me know if you make any progress.

Comment: Filters are no good, as the error occurs before they are called.  I submitted an issue to the play tracker: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7817